# How to overlap side menu over the current page in ionic?

Tags: ionic-framework

By default in Ionic side menu pushes the current page when the side menu button  is clicked.
But i need to overlap the side menu over the current page as in most of the apps.
How to do that?
Where should i change the code?
Just consider a default side menu template from ionic.

```
   <ion-side-menus enable-menu-with-back-views="false">
     <ion-side-menu-content>
    <ion-nav-bar class="bar-positive bar-blue">
     <ion-nav-back-button></ion-nav-back-button>
  <ion-nav-buttons side="left">
     <button class="button button-icon button-clear ion-navicon" menu-toggle="left"></button>
      </ion-nav-buttons>
       <ion-nav-buttons side="right">
       <a menu-close href="#/app/playlists" class="cancelbutton">
          <button class="button button-icon button-clear " ng-hide=cancelflag>cancel</button>
         </a>
         </ion-nav-buttons>
       </ion-nav-bar>
        <ion-nav-view name="menuContent"animation="fade-in-out"></ion-nav-view>
         </ion-side-menu-content>

    <ion-side-menu side="left">
<ion-header-bar class="bar-positive bar-image sidemenu-header">
  <h1 class="title title-left">{{currentuser}}</h1>
</ion-header-bar>
<ion-content>
  <ion-list>
    <!-- <ion-item menu-close href="#/testing">
      testinglogin
    </ion-item> -->
            <ion-item menu-close href="#/app/home" ng-show=adminflag>
      <label class="item-input labelclearpadding">
        <i class="icon paddingicon"><img src="img/user.png" alt="" class="placeholder dateicon"/></i>
        all details
      </label>
    </ion-item>
  </ion-list>
  <ion-list>
               </ion-list>
   </ion-content>
  </ion-side-menu>
  </ion-side-menus>
```

Answer (score 7):

I am working on **ionic 2** and this is helpful for the same only.
I was also searching for the same issue-
I read the [document here.](http://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/api/components/menu/Menu/)
Menu Types explain very clearly to add type= "overlay" and got my task accomplished

```
<ion-menu [content]="content" side="right" type="overlay">
   ................
     ...............
       lines of code goes here
     ...............
   ................

</ion-menu>
```

Where -
Side => being toggle from right
type => display type of menu on current screen.

Answer (score 6):

This is only available native in Ionic Framework 2, as described here: http://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/api/components/menu/Menu/.

> Menu supports two display types: overlay, reveal and push. Overlay is the traditional Material Design drawer type, and Reveal is the traditional iOS type. By default, menus will use to the correct type for the platform, but this can be overriden using the type property:

```
<ion-menu type="overlay" [content]="mycontent">...</ion-menu>
```

Comment: i dont have a tag named <ion-menu> in any pages? what should i do?

Comment: how can i change my framework once i started the app?

Comment: You have to rewrite your application to Angular 2, there is some information here: http://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/getting-started/migration/. It is probably a better solution to include a third party extenstion instead.

Answer (score 4):

This is possible in ionic 1 by leveraging ng-class and the $ionicSideMenuDelegate.  There are 3 steps involved:

1. You will need to add a scope function to your controller for ng-class to reference that returns whether or not the menu is open:

```js
$scope.isMenuOpen = function() {  
    return $ionicSideMenuDelegate.isOpen();  
};
```

2. You will need to add a class that ng-class will set on the menu-content if the menu is open:

```css
.menu-content.menu-open {
  transform: translate3d(0px, 0px, 0px) !important;
  z-index: -1;
  opacity: 0.4;
}
```

The !important transform overrides the transform that ionic adds when the menu button is clicked so the menu-content stays in place.  The z-index and opacity are to make the menu-content appear in the background behind the menu.

3. Add the ng-class to your html:

```html
<ion-side-menus enable-menu-with-back-views="false">  
        <ion-side-menu-content ng-class="isMenuOpen() ? 'menu-open' : ''">  
            <ion-nav-bar class="bar-positive bar-blue">
                ...
```

And you're done!  Now whenever the menu is open, the menu-open class will get applied to menu-content and it will stay in place but fade to the background creating your overlay look.  The only drawback here is that nothing will be able to translate your menu-content since you've overridden that using !important, so keep that in mind if you are looking for other animations.

I have it working in my app with a left menu.  It should also work with a right menu since you are applying the dynamic class to the menu-content.

Answer (score 2):

Correct answer that of @henrikmerlander, however if you want a drawer component for Ionic 1 that always acts as on iOS device (overlay) you can use this:

https://github.com/beaver71/ionic-ion-drawer

And usage is really easy:

```
<drawer side="left">
    <ion-content>
     ....
    </ion-content>
</drawer>
```

Here is a working example: http://codepen.io/beaver71/pen/BKpRjM/

Comment: wher should i use this one? in html for side menu ? or html for pages?

Comment: I used it always on html templates of my views (pages), but I think there is no problem to use it in index html if drawer menu has to be the same for the whole app. It can't be used in side menu tag, it is an alternative.

Comment: are u sure it will overlap the current page?

Comment: check the codepen added to my answer. I forked the original project to my github account for some minor edits.

Comment: you need to modify the template... bye